# Connect laptop using Ubuntu 11.04 to TV?

Tags: 11.04, tv, vga

My laptop is Compaq presario cq42. I tried to connect my laptop (using ubuntu 11.04) to my TV with VGA cable. The bootloader menu and login screen are displayed on TV but after logged in, it showed NO SIGNAL. I tried to change resolution of TV but nothing change (do it in both Monitors and ATI analys control (admin)).

Here's my /etc/X11/xorg.conf :

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "amdcccle Layout"
    Screen      0  "amdcccle-Screen[1]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-LVDS"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1366x768"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "0-CRT1"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
    Option      "PreferredMode" "1366x768"
    Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
    Option      "Position" "0 0"
    Option      "Rotate" "normal"
    Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "amdcccle-Device[1]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    Option      "Monitor-LVDS" "0-LVDS"
    Option      "Monitor-CRT1" "0-CRT1"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default Screen"
    DefaultDepth     24
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "amdcccle-Screen[1]-0"
    Device     "amdcccle-Device[1]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Run : sudo lshw gives me :

```
 *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: M93 [Mobility Radeon HD 4500 Series]
                vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:45 memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:94000000-9400ffff memory:94020000-9403ffff
```

Please help !!

Comment: This isn't a programming question. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way to solve it myself. Hope this useful for someone need.
- Connect laptop to TV (VGA cable).
- Boot up the machine.
- GRUB menu and Login screen will be displayed on TV.
- LOG IN => NO SIGNAL on TV (don't worry)
- On the laptop, type in terminal this line:

```
sudo xrandr --auto
```

Everything should be displayed on TV too.

Go to Monitors preference (in System setting) and config the way you like.
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In opposition to fingering around with a system-created xorg.conf I'd suggest using the xrandr tool to adapt inferior-working LCD TVs. The following alternatives were tested with a Panasonic Viera Full-HD screen which nevertheless accepts only XGA (1024x768) and thereby a 4:3 aspect ratio as highest resolution on its VGA connector. Attached was a Lenovo IdeaPad S12 with a native resolution of 1280x800.

**For the sharpest possible TV rendering:** set aspect ratio on TV to 4:3. This will create black vertical left and right bars on the TV. Depending on the desired configuration, either choose dual screen operation and set auxiliary device (TV) to 1024*768, or use the "same image on both screens" feature of the respective settings tool and adapt overall resolution to 1024*768. For me, this is necessary if I want to play videos via Totem or VLC. In dual screen operation the video output window remains black, even though the sound is being played.

**For the largest possible display on the TV:** Set TV resolution to 16:9 (or automatic) but change pixel aspect ratio on the notebook for the secondary screen (in dual screen mode) to something around 1.4x1 by the appropriate xrandr command:

```
sudo xrandr --output VGA1 --scale 1.4x1
```

After that the simple and old Xwindows programs (like xterm) will look awkward since the typically used pixelized font structure is interpolated, but modern programs that utilize good scalable fonts will render quite a nice screen display.